# Проблема включения микрофона в программе C#

Tags: c#, распознавание-речи, microsoft-speech-sdk

я сделал голосового ассистента на Python, но решил, перейти на C#. По видеоуроку я написал этот код который должен слушать микрофон и писать цифру на экране. Код не выдает никаких ошибок, но при запуске микрофон не включается. Кто нибудь знает как это можно исправить?

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Windows.Forms;
            using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;

            namespace SpeechRecognition
            {
                public partial class Form1 : Form
                {
                    public Form1()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                    }

                    static Label l;

                    static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.7) l.Text = e.Result.Text;
                    }

                    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {
                        l = label1;

                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-Ru");
                        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
                        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);


                        Choices numbers = new Choices();
                        numbers.Add(new string[] { "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять" });


                        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
                        gb.Culture = ci;
                        gb.Append(numbers);


                        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
                        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

                        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `CultureInfo("ru-RU")`

Comment: Вот [инструкция](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/speech-recognition-making-wpf-listen/), правда для WPF.

Comment: а вы не знаете, что именно с этим кодом не так?